# hosts file with multiple entries crashes browsers

Tags: windows-xp, hosts-file

```
127.0.0.1 www.whatever.com

111.1.1.1 www.whatever.com

127.0.0.1 www.whatever.com
```

The `111.1.1.1` in the second line can be any non-127.0.0.1-address.

Under Windows XP, Firefox/Chrome.

Why is it that this configuration will crash a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Without reference to any specific operating system or browser environment, it seems reasonable to assume that it's not valid to have multiple entries for the same IP spanning multiple lines in your particular environment.

Comment: In fact, it's valid to have multiple entries for the same IP in Windows XP. 

I wonder how the hosts file be parsed.

Comment: I see.  Sorry, completely outside the domain of my experience.  I've retagged the question though to reflect your edit.